# header слева от ячеек collectionview

Tags: xcode, swift, uicollectionview

Как сделать чтоб header был слева и автоматически расширялся в зависимости от количества ячеек?
[image: так должно быть]

Answer (score 2):

Сделать контейнер, в него положить лейбл слева и коллекцию справа, и когда размер коллекции меняется менять размер лейбла.